# TOTALMTD Measure is not working in Power BI Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am creating a Power BI report where I have 1 Date table and another table, in which I have 2 columns as Date Column and Daily Target. I need to create a MTD Measure which will sum the current month to date daily targets. I am using this formula but it is not returning a correct result. Here is the formula I am using:

```
    MTD-Measure = CALCULATE(SUM(GroupByTableForMTD[Max Daily Target]),DATESMTD(tblDate[Date]))
```

Here is my Data Table.

[image]

Please help me to write a MTD measure. I will be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN: TOTALMTD Function (DAX)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634560.aspx)

```
MTD-Measure = TOTALMTD(SUM(GroupByTableForMTD[target]),GroupByTableForMTD[date],All(Table5))
```

[image]